# Change figure's location

Tags: floats

Any thoughts on how to slightly lower the position of this Figure so that the page (figure+table) is vertically centred?[image]

Comment: merge figure and table in one float. for more, please provide *mwe* (minimal working example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` containing the caption of the figure and  the code of your table.

Comment: by default float pages are vertically centred, since you showed no input nor the page margins in the output it is impossible really to help unless you provide more information.

Comment: Solved with Zarko's suggestion, thanks!